# I am having trouble with function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I was doing a course on Udemy to learn JavaScript by making a pong game but when I came across this part I was really confused. What do the parameters do? Are they variables? If they are variables can they be accessed out of the function? I just don't understand! Please explain it to me!  :(

I don't even understand what he's trying to do!

I think he was trying to draw or fill it in or something.

this is the code:

```
function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, drawColor) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0,Math.PI*2, true);
}
```

Comment: Better read more about functions.

Comment: Google "programming what is a function."  Also please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: `->` http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: Yes, they declare variables that can be only accessed inside the function. They will get filled with the arguments when the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable is simply a named value.  Instead of hard-coding values everywhere:

```
100 /* speed of my canary */ + 10 /* current speed bonus */
```

we can "name" our values and pass them around (and even change them as we need to without re-writing the rest of our program):

```
var speedOfMyCanary = 100;
var speedBonus = 10;

speedOfMyCanary + speedBonus // still 110;
```

A function parameter is simply a variable scoped to a function:

```
function doWork(a, b, c) {
  // Do work here later with a, b, and c.
}
```

is the same (conceptually) as:

```
var a, b, c;
function doWork() {
  // Do work here later with a and b and c
}
// Call do work now
doWork();
delete a;
delete b;
delete c;
```

if we could carry around the `var a, b, c` and `delete a, b, c` with our `doWork` without copy-pasting it.

That is to say, when we call:

```
doWork(1, 2, 3);
```

It is (again, *conceptually*) the same as:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
function doWork() {
  // Do work here later with a and b and c
}
doWork();
delete a;
delete b;
delete c;
```

Function parameters get us a few extra benefits:

First, the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` are not accessible to code outside our function:

```
function doWork(a, b, c) {
  // a, b, and c are all accessible here
  return a + b + c;
}

// But we can't access those values out here
// if we try we'll get:
a // ReferenceError - `a` is not defined
```

The *bonus* benefit is that our callers don't have to worry about what we call our inputs internally - if we change the names from `a`, `b`, and `c` to `x`, `y`, and `z` our calling code remains unchanged:

```
function doWork(x, y, z) {}
doWork(1, 2, 3)  // STILL WORKS :-)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I kinda... sorta... figured it out hours ago on wikipedia.   XD    but I'll still mark yours as helpful  XD

Answer (score 0):

Those parameter's cant be access outside the function. Take a look to this: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Also, take a look to this link for understanding what variables are: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp.

What he is trying to do is to draw a circle giving it the color, location, and radius.

In udemy search for this course:https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-javascript-course/